# JPA: Pre-allocate ID block not work fine

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

I'm trying to manage the ID generation through the annotation @TableGenerator with allocationSize default. As I understand it, to avoid updating the row for every single identifier that gets requested, an allocation size is used. In theory, the provider should pre-allocate a block of identifiers equal to the value of allocationSize - 50 in this case - and then give out identifiers from memory as requested until the block is used up or the transaction comes to an end.

I Use Eclipselink (EL) with JBoss 7.1.

The problem is that this does not happen. Inserting 3 records in the table Students, EL pre allocates for each record a block of 50 ID, even if the transaction is the same. Then, for each record, there is always access to the table. From the logs I see 3 pre allocations and three pairs of select/update query for the ID and the IDs are generated 1- 51 -101 and the sequence has as its final value 150. Piece of log

```
Connection acquired from connection pool
UPDATE SEQUENCE SET SEQ_COUNT = SEQ_COUNT + ? WHERE SEQ_NAME = ?
bind => [50, TABLE_SEQ]
SELECT SEQ_COUNT FROM SEQUENCE WHERE SEQ_NAME = ?
bind => [TABLE_SEQ]
local sequencing preallocation for TABLE_SEQ: objects: 50 , first: 1, last: 50
Connection released to connection pool [default].

Connection acquired from connection pool
UPDATE SEQUENCE SET SEQ_COUNT = SEQ_COUNT + ? WHERE SEQ_NAME = ?
bind => [50, TABLE_SEQ]
SELECT SEQ_COUNT FROM SEQUENCE WHERE SEQ_NAME = ?
bind => [TABLE_SEQ]
local sequencing preallocation for TABLE_SEQ: objects: 50 , first: 51, last: 100
Connection released to connection pool [default].
```

Being a single transaction, I expected sequential IDs (1-2-3) and the final value of the sequence 50. 
Where am I wrong? I tried to do research on the forum but I can not even solve the problem.
Below is the simple test code.
Thanks for the help.

Entity Student

```
@Entity
@Table(name="STUDENTS")
public class Student implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4771385985502937621L;

    @TableGenerator(name="TABLE_SEQ")
    @Id @Column(name="ID_STUDENT") @GeneratedValue(generator="TABLE_SEQ")
    private int idStudent;

    private String name;

    public int getIdStudent() {
        return idStudent;
    }

    public void setIdStudent(int idStudent) {
        this.idStudent = idStudent;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name= name;
    }
}
```

EJB

```
@Stateless(name="EJBStudent")
public class EJBStudent implements EJBStudentRemote
{
    @PersistenceContext(unitName="JPA_Test")
    private EntityManager manager;

    public EJBStudent() {
    }


    @Override
    public void insertStudents() 
    {
        manager.getTransaction().begin();

        Student student1 = new Student();
        student1.setName("Anna");
        manager.persist(student1);

        Student student2 = new Student();
        student2.setName("Paolo");
        manager.persist(student2);

            Student student3 = new Student();
        student3.setName("Luigi");
        manager.persist(student3);

        manager.flush();
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
@Chris thanks for response.

This is the finest log. I only noticed a major difference. For each insert, it create a different connection. However, if run the query suggested by @wypieprz first of all persist, the connection is always the same.

```
Invoking org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.insertStudent    
[EL Finer]: connection: 2014-04-26 18:05:14.228--ServerSession(320769650)--Thread(Thread[EJB default - 1,5,EJB default])--client acquired: 1096067977
[EL Finer]: transaction: 2014-04-26 18:05:14.236--ClientSession(1096067977)--Thread(Thread[EJB default - 1,5,EJB default])--acquire unit of work: 698749338
[EL Finest]: transaction: 2014-04-26 18:05:14.237--UnitOfWork(698749338)--Thread(Thread[EJB default - 1,5,EJB default])--persist() operation called on: jpa.test.model.Student@55cdaad2.
[EL Finest]: connection: 2014-04-26 18:05:14.238--ServerSession(320769650)--Connection(118375432)--Thread(Thread[EJB default - 1,5,EJB default])--Connection acquired from connection pool [default].
[EL Finest]: query: 2014-04-26 18:05:14.24--ClientSession(1096067977)--Thread(Thread[EJB default - 1,5,EJB default])--Execute query DataModifyQuery(name="TABLE_SEQ" sql="UPDATE SEQUENCE SET SEQ_COUNT = SEQ_COUNT + #PREALLOC_SIZE WHERE SEQ_NAME = #SEQ_NAME")
[EL Finest]: connection: 2014-04-26 18:05:14.242--ClientSession(1096067977)--Thread(Thread[EJB default - 1,5,EJB default])--reconnecting to external connection pool
[EL Fine]: sql: 2014-04-26 18:05:14.249--ClientSession(1096067977)--Connection(1243300871)--Thread(Thread[EJB default - 1,5,EJB default])--UPDATE SEQUENCE SET SEQ_COUNT = SEQ_COUNT + ? WHERE SEQ_NAME = ?
    bind => [50, TABLE_SEQ]
[EL Finest]: query: 2014-04-26 18:05:14.252--ClientSession(1096067977)--Thread(Thread[EJB default - 1,5,EJB default])--Execute query ValueReadQuery(name="TABLE_SEQ" sql="SELECT SEQ_COUNT FROM SEQUENCE WHERE SEQ_NAME = #SEQ_NAME")
[EL Fine]: sql: 2014-04-26 18:05:14.253--ClientSession(1096067977)--Connection(1243300871)--Thread(Thread[EJB default - 1,5,EJB default])--SELECT SEQ_COUNT FROM SEQUENCE WHERE SEQ_NAME = ?
    bind => [TABLE_SEQ]
[EL Finest]: sequencing: 2014-04-26 18:05:14.256--ClientSession(1096067977)--Connection(1243300871)--Thread(Thread[EJB default - 1,5,EJB default])--local sequencing preallocation for TABLE_SEQ: objects: 50 , first: 1, last: 50
[EL Finest]: connection: 2014-04-26 18:05:14.258--ServerSession(320769650)--Connection(118375432)--Thread(Thread[EJB default - 1,5,EJB default])--Connection released to connection pool [default].
[EL Finest]: sequencing: 2014-04-26 18:05:14.259--UnitOfWork(698749338)--Thread(Thread[EJB default - 1,5,EJB default])--assign sequence to the object (1 -> jpa.test.model.Student@55cdaad2)
[org.hibernate.validator.util.Version] (EJB default - 1) Hibernate Validator 4.2.0.Final
[EL Finest]: transaction: 2014-04-26 18:05:14.325--UnitOfWork(698749338)--Thread(Thread[EJB default - 1,5,EJB default])--persist() operation called on: jpa.test.model.Student@59887d29.
[EL Finest]: connection: 2014-04-26 18:05:14.326--ServerSession(320769650)--Connection(265370795)--Thread(Thread[EJB default - 1,5,EJB default])--Connection acquired from connection pool [default].
[EL Finest]: query: 2014-04-26 18:05:14.327--ClientSession(1096067977)--Thread(Thread[EJB default - 1,5,EJB default])--Execute query DataModifyQuery(name="TABLE_SEQ" sql="UPDATE SEQUENCE SET SEQ_COUNT = SEQ_COUNT + ? WHERE SEQ_NAME = ?")
[EL Finest]: connection: 2014-04-26 18:05:14.328--ClientSession(1096067977)--Thread(Thread[EJB default - 1,5,EJB default])--reconnecting to external connection pool
[EL Fine]: sql: 2014-04-26 18:05:14.329--ClientSession(1096067977)--Connection(1910900393)--Thread(Thread[EJB default - 1,5,EJB default])--UPDATE SEQUENCE SET SEQ_COUNT = SEQ_COUNT + ? WHERE SEQ_NAME = ?
    bind => [50, TABLE_SEQ]
[EL Finest]: query: 2014-04-26 18:05:14.331--ClientSession(1096067977)--Thread(Thread[EJB default - 1,5,EJB default])--Execute query ValueReadQuery(name="TABLE_SEQ" sql="SELECT SEQ_COUNT FROM SEQUENCE WHERE SEQ_NAME = ?")
[EL Fine]: sql: 2014-04-26 18:05:14.332--ClientSession(1096067977)--Connection(1910900393)--Thread(Thread[EJB default - 1,5,EJB default])--SELECT SEQ_COUNT FROM SEQUENCE WHERE SEQ_NAME = ?
    bind => [TABLE_SEQ]
[EL Finest]: sequencing: 2014-04-26 18:05:14.334--ClientSession(1096067977)--Connection(1910900393)--Thread(Thread[EJB default - 1,5,EJB default])--local sequencing preallocation for TABLE_SEQ: objects: 50 , first: 51, last: 100
[EL Finest]: connection: 2014-04-26 18:05:14.335--ServerSession(320769650)--Connection(265370795)--Thread(Thread[EJB default - 1,5,EJB default])--Connection released to connection pool [default].
[EL Finest]: sequencing: 2014-04-26 18:05:14.336--UnitOfWork(698749338)--Thread(Thread[EJB default - 1,5,EJB default])--assign sequence to the object (51 -> jpa.test.model.Student@59887d29)
[EL Finest]: transaction: 2014-04-26 18:05:14.337--UnitOfWork(698749338)--Thread(Thread[EJB default - 1,5,EJB default])--persist() operation called on: jpa.test.model.Student@20f5e794.
[EL Finest]: connection: 2014-04-26 18:05:14.338--ServerSession(320769650)--Connection(1882633843)--Thread(Thread[EJB default - 1,5,EJB default])--Connection acquired from connection pool [default].
[EL Finest]: query: 2014-04-26 18:05:14.338--ClientSession(1096067977)--Thread(Thread[EJB default - 1,5,EJB default])--Execute query DataModifyQuery(name="TABLE_SEQ" sql="UPDATE SEQUENCE SET SEQ_COUNT = SEQ_COUNT + ? WHERE SEQ_NAME = ?")
[EL Finest]: connection: 2014-04-26 18:05:14.339--ClientSession(1096067977)--Thread(Thread[EJB default - 1,5,EJB default])--reconnecting to external connection pool
[EL Fine]: sql: 2014-04-26 18:05:14.34--ClientSession(1096067977)--Connection(402944403)--Thread(Thread[EJB default - 1,5,EJB default])--UPDATE SEQUENCE SET SEQ_COUNT = SEQ_COUNT + ? WHERE SEQ_NAME = ?
    bind => [50, TABLE_SEQ]
[EL Finest]: query: 2014-04-26 18:05:14.342--ClientSession(1096067977)--Thread(Thread[EJB default - 1,5,EJB default])--Execute query ValueReadQuery(name="TABLE_SEQ" sql="SELECT SEQ_COUNT FROM SEQUENCE WHERE SEQ_NAME = ?")
[EL Fine]: sql: 2014-04-26 18:05:14.343--ClientSession(1096067977)--Connection(402944403)--Thread(Thread[EJB default - 1,5,EJB default])--SELECT SEQ_COUNT FROM SEQUENCE WHERE SEQ_NAME = ?
    bind => [TABLE_SEQ]
[EL Finest]: sequencing: 2014-04-26 18:05:14.345--ClientSession(1096067977)--Connection(402944403)--Thread(Thread[EJB default - 1,5,EJB default])--local sequencing preallocation for TABLE_SEQ: objects: 50 , first: 101, last: 150
[EL Finest]: connection: 2014-04-26 18:05:14.346--ServerSession(320769650)--Connection(1882633843)--Thread(Thread[EJB default - 1,5,EJB default])--Connection released to connection pool [default].
[EL Finest]: sequencing: 2014-04-26 18:05:14.347--UnitOfWork(698749338)--Thread(Thread[EJB default - 1,5,EJB default])--assign sequence to the object (101 -> jpa.test.model.Student@20f5e794)
[EL Finer]: transaction: 2014-04-26 18:05:14.348--UnitOfWork(698749338)--Thread(Thread[EJB default - 1,5,EJB default])--begin unit of work flush
[EL Finest]: query: 2014-04-26 18:05:14.351--UnitOfWork(698749338)--Thread(Thread[EJB default - 1,5,EJB default])--Execute query InsertObjectQuery(jpa.test.model.Student@59887d29)
[EL Finest]: connection: 2014-04-26 18:05:14.353--ServerSession(320769650)--Connection(1582457600)--Thread(Thread[EJB default - 1,5,EJB default])--Connection acquired from connection pool [default].
[EL Finest]: connection: 2014-04-26 18:05:14.354--ClientSession(1096067977)--Thread(Thread[EJB default - 1,5,EJB default])--reconnecting to external connection pool
[EL Fine]: sql: 2014-04-26 18:05:14.354--ClientSession(1096067977)--Connection(1927398752)--Thread(Thread[EJB default - 1,5,EJB default])--INSERT INTO STUDENTS (ID_STUDENT, NAME) VALUES (?, ?)
bind => [51, Paolo]

[EL Finest]: query: 2014-04-26 18:05:14.37--UnitOfWork(698749338)--Thread(Thread[EJB default - 1,5,EJB default])--Execute query InsertObjectQuery(jpa.test.model.Student@55cdaad2)
[EL Fine]: sql: 2014-04-26 18:05:14.371--ClientSession(1096067977)--Connection(1927398752)--Thread(Thread[EJB default - 1,5,EJB default])--INSERT INTO STUDENTS (ID_STUDENT, NAME) VALUES (?, ?)
    bind => [1, Anna]
[EL Finest]: query: 2014-04-26 18:05:14.373--UnitOfWork(698749338)--Thread(Thread[EJB default - 1,5,EJB default])--Execute query InsertObjectQuery(jpa.test.model.Student@20f5e794)
[EL Fine]: sql: 2014-04-26 18:05:14.373--ClientSession(1096067977)--Connection(1927398752)--Thread(Thread[EJB default - 1,5,EJB default])--INSERT INTO STUDENTS (ID_STUDENT, NAME) VALUES (?, ?)
    bind => [101, Luigi]
[EL Finer]: transaction: 2014-04-26 18:05:14.375--UnitOfWork(698749338)--Thread(Thread[EJB default - 1,5,EJB default])--end unit of work flush
[EL Finer]: transaction: 2014-04-26 18:05:14.376--UnitOfWork(698749338)--Thread(Thread[EJB default - 1,5,EJB default])--resume unit of work
Exiting org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.insertStudent
Business method insertStudent in org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation takes 5878 ms to execute
18:05:14,409 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (Remoting "pc" task-1) JBAS011806: Channel end notification received, closing channel Channel ID 03cefe33 (inbound) of Remoting connection 3138554d to /127.0.0.1:65303
```

Comment: What is returned from the following query: `select * from SEQUENCE where SEQ_NAME = 'TABLE_SEQ'` ?

Comment: As before, thank you so much response. 
Is there anything that I did not understand. I execute the query you told me **before every persists** and it worked. Are generated id in order sequeziale (1-2-3) and the sequence is 50. But if I delete the query, I have the problem again. 
What's going on?

Comment: The code shown calls manager.getTransaction().begin(); and uses flush, but does not commit the transaction, so it should rollback when garbage collected.  Can you turn on EclipseLink logging to finest and show the logs generated for the insertStudents method?

Comment: Post update with log.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.
In order to work well with EclipseLink transactions, is must specify (in the persistence.xml file) which server we are using, in my case:

```
<property name="eclipselink.target-server" value="JBoss"/>
```